# How to compare a string to any object in the list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, generator-expression, set-comprehension

```
Name_list = [
    ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']
]

Name = 'Name 3'

if Name == 'any name in the list':
    print('Name is in the list')
```

How can I check if "Name 3" is in the list?

And also when the list looks like this:

```
    list_1 = [
    ['Name 1'],
    ['Name 2'],
    ['Name 3']
]
```

Comment: `if Name in Name_list:`

Comment: As an alternative, you can do ```if any(Name==name for name in Name_list)```

Comment: you edited the question to change the scope slightly after 2 people had answered, please don't do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `any`

```
if any(Name in sublist for sublist in Name_list):
    print('Name is in the list')
```

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
to [flatten the *list of lists*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/967621) in which you search, thus converting it into an ordinary list (in which you use `in` to search for `name`):

```
name = 'Name 3'

list_1 = [
    ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']
]

if name in [item for sublist in list_1 for item in sublist]:
    print('Name is in the list')

list_1 = [
    ['Name 1'],
    ['Name 2'],
    ['Name 3']
]

if name in [item for sublist in list_1 for item in sublist]:
    print('Name is in the list')
```

Note that as *MisterMiyagi* mentioned in the comment, you can also use [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
if name in {item for sublist in list_1 for item in sublist}:
    print('Name is in the list')
```

Or you can use [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions):

```
if name in (item for sublist in list_1 for item in sublist):
    print('Name is in the list')
```

These are possibly faster and/or more memory-efficient than list comprehension under some circumstances, such as large lists, or lists with many duplicates.

**SEE ALSO:**

[Generator expressions vs. list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/967621)

Comment: Heads up that this also works with generator expressions and set expressions instead of list comprehensions. These are more space efficient / possibly faster.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for the great comment, expanded the answer to include your suggestion!

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask how could I check if the name is not in the list, do I need to only change the "if name in" part?

Comment: @Eskimo868 Yes, to check if the name is **not** in the list, just use `if not name in ...` in all cases. Or use `if name not in ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
if Name in Name_list[0]:
    print(Name)
```

The `Name_list[0]` is because, you are creating a list inside a list. So, Name_list contains a list inside it. If you want to access the list inside Name_list, you will have to use the list index operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
Name = ''
Name_list = []
Name_list_v2 = []
if len(Name_list)==1:
    Name_list_v2=Name_list[0]
elif len(Name_list)>1:
    for names in Name_list:
        Name_list_v2.append(names[0])
else:
    print("Input formatted incorrectly")
for names in Name_list_v2:
    if names == Name:
        print("Name is in the list.")
    else:
        print("Name is not in the list")
```

Line by line description of what happens:

- line 1 sets the `Name` variable
- line 2 is where you input the list of names (you can format it as either `[['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']]` or `[['Name 1'], ['Name 2'], ['Name 3']]` (you don't have to use three variables)
- line 3 creates `Name_list_v2`, which will eventually be formatted as `['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']` regardless of which way you chose to input it
- lines 4&5 check if the list is formatted as `[['Name 1', Name 2', 'Name 3']]`, and if it is converts it into `['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']`
- lines 6-8 check if the list is formatted as `[['Name 1'], ['Name 2'], ['Name 3']]`, and if it is, change it to `['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']`
- lines 9&10 print an error message if the input was formatted wrong
- lines 11-15 check if the name you inputted on line 1 is in `Names_list_v2`, and print a response.